# Why hard coded value for p:inputText in p:dataTable showing blank value?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

```
       <p:column headerText="serial no">
        <h:outputText value="#{helloBean.serialNo}"></h:outputText>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="name">
            <p:inputText value="srikanth"></p:inputText>
       </p:column>

  </p:dataTable>
```

The above is populated by a list of 10 objects with serial numbers from 1 to 10. The datatable renders with 10 rows with first column showing serial number correctly but the second column in all the rows is shown blank even though i hard coded column value.

What is the reason behind this!!!!

Comment: By blank you mean an HTML input element is rendered with no text in the box?  If so can you post the HTML code of the input element that is rendered?

Comment: try using :  <p:inputText value="srikanth" size="10"></p:inputText>

Comment: @Walker It didn't help :)

Comment: @MarkRobinson Yes Html input element with no text. Rendered html code 
<input id="myform:myTable:2:j_idt20" name="myform:myTable:2:j_idt20" type="text" size="10" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">

Answer (score 0):

Use h:outputText tag for second column as well, this will render the values. If you want to provide input, use p:inputText tag.

```
<p:column headerText="name">
<h:outputText value="srikanth"></h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Comment: The question is about why static value is not being shown inside data table when it is displaying outside. Outside I mean <p:inputText> with hard coded outside of datatable

Answer (score 0):

i think the way dataTable in JSF works is that you have two important attributes value and var defined at table level, here value is a collection / arraylist of POJOs which you want to iterate and val is one item in the list / POJO at a time. in table columns using JSF components value property, you can access the value of particular properties of POJO and display their values. Number of rows displayed in table will depend on size of arrayList. For example Employee table with different attributes of employee in different columns. so one good way seems to be iterating over table's value property and rendering columns accordingly.

here since you are displaying same constant value for name for all the columns, you can use a string constant defined in bean and access it from the value property of the component and it should work.

it was little bit surprising that using

```
 <p:inputText value="srikanth"></p:inputText>
```

outside a dataTable on a page results in html code `<input type="text" value = "srikanth" ...>`  but it does not work that way inside a dataTable.

after using footer facet of column, i could see the inputText value :

```
  <p:dataTable>                 
       <p:column >
        <f:facet name = "header">name</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="footer"><p:inputText value="srikanth"></p:inputText></f:facet>
       </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

the code above could generate an html `<input value="srikanth"...>` inside table's footer . 
It seems like static content is better suited to be placed inside table columns header and footer area while actual content should be provided through dataTable's value and var attributes.